# Compare time duration values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have to compare the time duration of the recorded audio file against a fixed time duration value of 10 mins (10:00). The duration of the audio file is a string.
Doing string comparison works fine if the format of recorded files duration and the format of the fixed duration is same i.e `mm:ss`. If the audio file has duration of format hh:mm:ss , it gives false values in certain cases.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: You can convert the string to seconds then compare with 10 * 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this String Extension to calculate total minutes from string

```
extension String {
    func getTimeInSeconds()-> Int? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss" //Your date format
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current //Current time zone
        var date = Date()
        if let getDate = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {//according to date format your date string
            date = getDate //Convert String to Date
        } else {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            if let getDate = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {//according to date format your date string
                date = getDate //Convert String to Date
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,.second], from: date)
        let hour = components.hour ?? 0
        let minute = components.minute ?? 0
        let seconds = components.second ?? 0
        return (hour * 360) + minute*60 + seconds
    }
}
```

You can use this extension like this

```
 let getSeconds = "01:20".getTimeInSeconds()
```

it will cover both formats mm:ss and hh:mm:ss and return seconds ... you can use these seconds to compare instead of string